# com.opencv.* package cannot be found in opencv for android example

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

Does anybody got run [this example](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/OpenCV/CVCamera_Canny.zip) compiled?

I get the message that the following packages cannot not be found:

```
import com.opencv.camera.CameraConfig;
import com.opencv.camera.NativePreviewer;
import com.opencv.camera.NativeProcessor;
import com.opencv.camera.NativeProcessor.PoolCallback;
import com.opencv.jni.image_pool;
import com.opencv.opengl.GL2CameraViewer;
```

The scurril thing is, that the [opencv for android sdk from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.5/) only contains the domainspaces `org.opencv.*` and not `com.opencv`. Also there is no camera package in it...

Does anybody had the same problem?

Comment: The code is also hosted here: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/android/apps?rev=3724